# Push a route (Moving from vueJS to nuxtJS)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I am converting a VueJS project to Nuxt.js and I have a problem understanding how nuxt handles routing. Its documentation doesn't say anything about Pushing a route.

Using VueJS I have the following in a component.

```
 //template
 <input class="" type="search"
        name="q" id="q" v-model="q"
        @keyup.enter="submitSearch"
 >
 //script
  methods: {
        submitSearch() {
            this.$route.push({name: 'search', query: {q: this.q}});

            //also tried the following
            //nuxt.$router.push({name: 'search', query: {q: this.q}});

        }
    }
```

But this doesn't do a thing in Nuxt. Putting an alert('hi); inside the submitSearch fires fine but I am never redirected to the route.

The goal here is when the user presses enter in the searchbar, to be redirected to /search?q=blablabla

**EDIT:**

The problem is that the user is redirected to `/?q=blablabla` instead of `/search?`..

I just realized that this is because there are different names for multilingual routes.

How am I going to push to a route name that instead of '`search`' is named `search__en` dynamically?

Comment: isn't it still "this.$router.push...?"

Comment: Also refer to this issue: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2737

Comment: Thanks @DevinFields, I updated my question.

Comment: there still might not be enough information. Is that the complete vue file? Can you post your router configuration?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The way I finally did was:

```js
this.$router.push({path: this.localePath('search'), query: {q: this.q}});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how it could be done in Nuxt3, with the Composition API

```html
<script setup>
const router = useRouter()
const moveToIndex = () => router.push({ name: 'about' })
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="moveToIndex">move to about page</button>
</template>
```

The Options API is still working in the same exact way.

Answer (score 2):

Faced same problem with Nuxt v2.14.12. After some digging found `router` object under `this.$nuxt.$options.router` which is a Nuxt [Helper](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/$nuxt). Currently `this.$nuxt.$options.router.push()` works fine.

Comment: You don't need to go that deep, as shown by the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but while working with hashing I found this to work well. Will come back to edit this if there are any issues in the future.

this.$router.push(`#${hash}`);

Comment: This answer is in the wrong place, but you definitely helped me. Thanks. Also I realized stack overflow converts the backticks you used.

Answer (score 0):

For Nuxt3:

```
const router = useRouter();

router.push({ path: '/home' });
router.push({ path: 'project-list' });
router.replace({ name: 'project-list' });
```

And list of useful methods:

```
router.back();
router.forward();
router.go();
```

Answer (score 0):

use [NavigateTo](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/navigate-to)

```js
  navigateTo("/reports/" + reportId);
```